# Multiple Acitve LANs

Tags: windows-7, multiple-computers

I am running Windows 7 on multiple computers. Each computer has its own internet connection on one LAN (Wireless) and a wired LAN connection which hosts a shared printer.  Assuming I turn DHCP services off on the wired LAN, what would a typical network configuration look like?

GOAL: Each computer accesses the internet over its private wireless connection and accesses the printer over the shared wired LAN.

Comment: You're not not giving us much to work with here.  How many routers?  what is a "private" wireless connection?

Answer (score 0):

You need something called a "Switch". This is simpler than a router. A router is not needed in this case because all of the wired network connections for the PC's will be on one network as will the printer.

Plug the laptops and the printer into the switch using standard network cables can configure them all to have IP addresses in the same range - making sure that range is different to the one used for Wi-Fi.

For example if all of the Wi-Fi connections use addresses in the range 192.168.0.1 - .255 then use the range 192.168.1.1 - .255

You can use any range that starts 192.168.x.x

You should also make sure that the netmask for both networks is 255.255.255.0 so that broadcasts from one network cannot leak to the other.

Simpler however is to get something to put the printer onto the Wi-Fi!